# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\phi-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{3\ln^2(\phi)}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How do we prove this?
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\phi-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{3\ln^2(\phi)}{4}$$
> where $\phi:=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ is the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\phi-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{\phi-1})^{2n}}{2n+1}\left(1-\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{\phi-1})^{2n}}{2n+1}-\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)(\sqrt{\phi-1})^{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=J-I\\
\text{where}\\
J&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{\phi-1})^{2n}}{2n+1}\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}|_{x=\sqrt{\phi-1}}\\
\text{and}\\
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}&=\frac{1}{x}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int x^{2n}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\\
\text{So}\\
J&=\frac{1}{2x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)|_{x=\sqrt{\phi-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\phi-1}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\phi-1}}{1-\sqrt{\phi-1}}\right) 
\end{align*}

But how do we calculate $I$ to get the result.

Comment: Something's off here.  Left side $> 1$ (consider the $n=0$ term), right side $< \pi^2/12 < 1$.

Comment: Just to be clear, your $\phi $ is the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$?

Comment: Maple's Integer Relations package does not find any relation between the left side, $\pi^2$ and $\ln(\phi)^2$.  Where did you get your equation?

Comment: @Robert israel I found this relationship on one of the sites and I did not prove it at that time, and when I tried now, I did not reach that. Perhaps you can help me with this, even if it is not equal to this result, you can give us an idea to reach the result. Thank you.

Comment: @ Robert israel I'm going to adjust it so that the question becomes clear though this series is convergent

Comment: The series $\sum x^{2n} /(2n+1)^2$ equals $\dfrac{1}{2x}\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}\log\left(\dfrac {1+t}{1-t}\right)\,dt$ and your desired sum is given by $x=\sqrt{\phi-1}$.

Comment: You may try the methods given in various answers of your earlier question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3780024/72031) to evaluate the sum (hopefully).

Comment: @paramanand Singh thank' sir

Comment: Ramanujan studied the function $f(x) =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan t} {t} \, dt$ and clearly if we define $g(x) =-if(ix) $ your sum is $(1/x)g(x)$ with $x=\sqrt{\phi-1}$. Ramanujan mentions $f(x) - f(1/x)=(\pi/2)\log x$. But not sure if this would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111508/discussion-between-bachamohamed-and-paramanand-singh).

Comment: @blue thank's for edited

Comment: Numerically, I got for the serie $\displaystyle \approx \color{red}{1.0919}$ while the RHS becomes $\displaystyle \approx \color{red}{0.6488}$ in your proposed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula has a typo, it should be :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\phi-1)^{\color{red}{2n+1}}}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{3\ln^2(\phi)}{4}$$

It´s an instance of [Legendre's Chi-Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresChi-Function.html) evaluated at $x=\phi-1$

Here is the proof:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac14\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x^2)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
 \end{aligned}
$$

Hence

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}&=\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)-\frac14\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x^2)\\
&=\frac12\left(\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)-\mathrm{Li}_{2}(-x)\right)
 \end{aligned}
$$

Letting $x=\phi-1$ and noting that $\phi-1=\frac{1}{\phi}$ we obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\phi-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}&=\frac12\left(\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{\phi}\right)-\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi^2}{10}-\ln^2(\phi)+\frac{\pi^2}{15}-\frac{\ln^2(\phi)}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{3\ln^2(\phi)}{4} \qquad \blacksquare
 \end{aligned}
$$

Where we used that

$
\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)+\mathrm{Li}_{2}(-x)=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(x^{2}\right)
$

and

$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1}{\phi}\right) &=\frac{\pi^{2}}{10}-\ln ^{2} \phi \\
\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right) &=\frac{\ln ^{2} \phi}{2}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{15} \\
\end{aligned}
$

A proof of these last two relations between dilogs and the golden ratio can be found here in my [blog](https://mymatexnotes.blogspot.com/2021/06/relations-between-dilogarithms-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With the *Golden Ratio* $\ds{\phi \equiv {\root{5} + 1 \over 2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\phi - 1}^{n} \over
\pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{~\mbox{Note that}\ \phi - 1 = {1 \over \phi}~}
\\[5mm] & =
\root{\phi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\phi^{-1/2}}^{2n + 1} \over
\pars{2n + 1}^{2}} = \root{\phi}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\phi^{-1/2}}^{n } \over
n^{2}}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\root{\phi}\bracks{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over \root{\phi}} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over \root{\phi}}}}
\approx 1.0919
\end{align}